# Навигация iOS приложения

Tags: xcode, navigationcontroller, ios7, view

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с навигацией. Работаю с ксибами. Схема такая:

[image: img]

Вот мой код:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@implementation FirstViewController
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondViewController.title = @"View2";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
    thirdViewController.title = @"View3";

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {    //если выбрал item1 в таблице
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
        [secondViewTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

У меня вопросы:

1. Где создавать следующее представление? У меня получается, что оно создается в "предыдущем" классе: view2 создается в `FirstViewController`, view3 создается в `SecondViewController` и т.д. Где создавать объект `view` - в методе, который инициирует переход? Мне кажется, что у меня все неправильно, хотя переходы работают.
2. Проблемы с заголовками в `navigation bar`. Получается, что заголовок `view2` отображается только при переходе с `view1` на `view2`, но при переходе назад с `view3` на `view2` – заголовок исчезает. Гуглил, пробовал писать `self.title = @"name"` в методах `viewDidLoad`, `initWithNibName` - не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не парьтесь, все правильно делаете.
2. Про заголовок странно, не должен он вроде меняться при обратном переходе. Можете попробовать присваивать его не во viewDidLoad (ибо данный метод дергается на генерацию вида, а вид у вас никуда не делся - лежит себе в стеке навигейшена и прекрасно себя чувтвует), а во viewWillAppear, он вызывается каждый раз перед появлением вида на экране (перед анимацией)

Comment: Я так пробовал тоже – не работает. 
@implementation SecondViewController
`- (void)viewWillAppear {
    self.title = @"View2";
}`
Может с заголовком проблемы, потому что намудрил с UINavigationController? Его может через IB надо создавать с привязкой свойства и т д ?

Comment: по идее не должен, если все ходит то с ним все хорошо, точнее по полученным данным сказать ничего не могу. Вы как назад возвращаете, чем-то специальным или по стандартному беку?

Comment: Все по умолчанию, никаких кнопок и действий в UINavigationController не добавлял.